# Gnuplot: Different timefmt for both axes

Tags: gnuplot

I try to draw a graph with sunrise and sunset times around a year. This is my script for plotting:

```
set terminal png size 1000,500
set output "dose.png"
set xlabel "2018"
set label 1 'secs after midnight' at graph -0.08, graph 0.3 rotate
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m-%d"
set xtics "1",2592000,"365" out
set format x "%m-%d"
set ytics "0",3600,"86400" out
set title "sunrise and sunset at Oulu"
set key off
datafile="./f.data"
set yrange ["0":"86399"]
plot datafile using 1:2 w filledcurve x1 lc rgb "#BFD0FB", \
'' using 1:3 w filledcurve x2 lc rgb "#BFD0FB", \
'' using 1:4 w filledcurve x1 lc rgb "#7FA2F7", \
'' using 1:5 w filledcurve x2 lc rgb "#7FA2F7", \
'' using 1:6 w filledcurve x1 lc rgb "#3F74F3", \
'' using 1:7 w filledcurve x2 lc rgb "#3F74F3", \
'' using 1:8 w filledcurve x1 lc rgb "#0046F0", \
'' using 1:9 w filledcurve x2 lc rgb "#0046F0", \
'' using 1:10 w filledcurve x1 lc rgb "#002EA0", \
'' using 1:11 w filledcurve x2 lc rgb "#002EA0", \
'' using 1:12 w filledcurve x1 lc rgb "#001750", \
'' using 1:13 w filledcurve x2 lc rgb "#001750", \
'' using 1:14 w filledcurve x1 lc rgb "black", \
'' using 1:15 w filledcurve x2 lc rgb "black"
```

And here is a line from `f.data`:

```
4-23 15720 72660 15540 72780 15300 73020 15120 73200 11280 77100 3480 84840 0 86400
```

However, I want to change yticsk to hours, but I'm unable to way to do it. I want to see 10 instead of 36000 and 23 instead of 82800. How I can do that?

If needed, I can change format of data files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a better way, but this should work:

```
set ytics ("" 0)
do for [y = 0:23] {
   set ytics add (sprintf("%d",y) (y*3600))
}
```

The first `set` is to remove the defaults, then we loop through the values 0 to 23 and do a `set ytics add ("..." ...)` to add a new explicit label which is formed of a string and the y value where it should be placed.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my suggestion.
Simply set the y-format as timedate `"%H:%M"` or maybe better `"%tH:%M"`. In the first case you have daytime from `00:00` to `00:00`, in the latter case from `00:00` to `24:00`. Check `help time_specifiers`.

I assume you want to plot something like [this](https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/finland/oulu?month=4&year=2018).
Since you can have several twilight-time ranges in Oulu during the year, plotting might get a bit more difficult depending on the actual data format.

**Script:**

```
### plot date on x-axis and daytime on y-axis
reset session

$Data <<EOD
4-23 15720 72660 15540 72780 15300 73020 15120 73200 11280 77100 3480 84840 0 864007
4-24 15720 72660 15540 72780 15300 73020 15120 73200 11280 77100 3480 84840 0 864007
4-25 15720 72660 15540 72780 15300 73020 15120 73200 11280 77100 3480 84840 0 864007
4-26 15720 72660 15540 72780 15300 73020 15120 73200 11280 77100 3480 84840 0 864007
4-27 15720 72660 15540 72780 15300 73020 15120 73200 11280 77100 3480 84840 0 864007
4-28 15720 72660 15540 72780 15300 73020 15120 73200 11280 77100 3480 84840 0 864007
4-29 15720 72660 15540 72780 15300 73020 15120 73200 11280 77100 3480 84840 0 864007
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%m-%d"
set format x "%b %d" timedate
set xtics out
set yrange [0:86400]
set format y "%tH:%M" timedate
set ytics out

myColor(i) = word("0xBFD0FB 0x7FA2F7 0x3F74F3 0x0046F0 0x002EA0 0x001750 0x000000",i/2)  # integer division!
set key noautotitle

plot for [i=2:14:2] $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):i w filledcurves x1 lc rgb myColor(i), \
     for [i=3:15:2] $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):i w filledcurves x2 lc rgb myColor(i)
### end of script
```

**Result:** (I don't have the real data, so I just duplicated the first day)

[image]

Comment: You have good assumptions. Nowadays I've this one: https://ig.fi/sci/fff.html  If you want to try it, please click "Päivitä sijainti" and then input your coordinates, i.e. "65 N, 25 E" for Oulu or "38.9 N 77W" for Washington DC, then click "Tallenna/Päivitä" and then click white X from top-right corner of this modal window.

Comment: @Timppa cool, looks good. Is this done with gnuplot in the back?

Comment: oh yes. The frontend is written with html and jQuery, sunrise and sunset data comes from Astro::Sunrise module, coordinates and some other data is validated with my own perl script. Image of the Earth is rendered with xplanet.